# what I can when there is error while running electron app

Tags: node.js, npm, electron

I made my first electron app through electronjs documentation.
I ran the application using `npm start` command,
but that showing me this error

$ npm start

> my-electron-app@1.0.0 start C:\Users\aksha\OneDrive\Desktop\ElcDocStarter\my-electron-app
> electron .

```
'electron' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-electron-app@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-electron-app@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aksha\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-17T08_15_08_284Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you install electron as global module? `npm i -g electron`

Comment: Add the electron path, as path env, https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: No I didn't....

Comment: @NullDev thanks for your help it worked and my app is running now

Comment: Well, in that case I'll post it as answer so we can mark this question as resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Install `electron` as global NPM module:

```sh
npm i -g electron
```